# Swagger UI with App Services. Cant Execute gets because of missing Params to URL (ZUMO)

Tags: swagger

When I am trying to execute a get over my swagger UI I am issued this error:

```
{
  "title": "Missing ZUMO-API-VERSION",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The value of ZUMO-API-VERSION is not specified 
              in headers or query parameters"
}
```

This is an issue I am aware of, as the table endpoints are always:

https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/tables/TABLENAME?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0

So the URL ends on: `?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0`

If I tried this without the `?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0` I am also getting the missing zumo api version error in my browser; so clearly swagger is not sending them out.

How can I add this param to every request the UI does to the middleware?

This is the config:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo()
    {
        Title = "Skillbased Middleware API Info",
        Version = "v1"
    });
});


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Company API Testing v1");
});



  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50999",
      "sslPort": 44331
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "SkillbasedMiddleware": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7278;http://localhost:5147",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A working API call:

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstring);
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [User] u LEFT JOIN [PICTURE] p ON u.Id = p.BelongsToUserId WHERE u.Id = '"+userId+"'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            List<UserJoinPicture> results = new List<UserJoinPicture>();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var userItem = new UserJoinPicture
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                        Email = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Email")),
                        Telephone = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Telephone")),
                        Password = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Password")),
                        UniqueDeviceId = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("UniqueDeviceId")),
                        IsCompany = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("IsCompany")),
                        IsLive = reader.GetBoolean(reader.GetOrdinal("IsLive")),
                        Thumbnail = (byte[])reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Thumbnail"))
                    };

                    results.Add(userItem);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return results;
```

EDIT:

I tried to alter the controller which sets the endpoint to the table by adding the required param:

```
    [Route("tables/companybenefits?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0")]

    public class CompanyBenefitsController : TableController<CompanyBenefitsItem>
    {
        public CompanyBenefitsController(MigrationDbContext context) : base(new EntityTableRepository<CompanyBenefitsItem>(context))
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

But upon deploy of the middleware I am getting:

```
RoutePatternException: The literal section 'companybenefits?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0' is invalid. Literal sections cannot contain the '?' character.
```

Any tips on that maybe?

Comment: The issue is not swagger, swagger just reports what the code reports as the endpoint call. Can you provide a working Postman (or other tool) call to the api which works? I believe its your api that is not setup properly.

Comment: Hello, i posted you a working calling api code from the client. I doubt I can set the api up in a away that the zumo is no longer required.

Comment: That is a sql call to Zumo? What does that have to do with swagger?

Comment: your asking very good questions; when I deploythe middleware and am trying to connect to a table via the browser, i have to add the ZUMO param to the  end of the URL or else it will throw me an error. Now swagger tries the same thing, makes a request via the URL but does not know to add the ZUMO param. How can this be changed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was swagger; and this is how I solved it.

```
 public class SwaggerHeader : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (operation.Parameters == null)
                operation.Parameters = new List<OpenApiParameter>();

            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter
            {
                Name = "ZUMO-API-VERSION",
                In = ParameterLocation.Query,
                Required = true // set to false if this is optional
            });
        }
    }
```

Now I am picking the calls that do not require Id and put for ZUMO = "3.0.0" and everythign works.